# Datatables filtering to be dynamic between columns

Tags: jquery, datatable

When using column filtering in Datatables, I want it so that once the first column filter is chosen and the resulting dataset is rendered, that the other columns filters to be refined to what is shown.

See this example: https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

If you choose 'Developer' from the position filter, the location filter should refine to the 4 locations remaining. But instead they show all the locations from the original dataset. Is there any way to make it refine them down as each filter is applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to hide options in `drawCallback`

```
drawCallback: function() {
  var api = this.api();
  let data = api.rows({
    filter: 'applied'
  }).data();
  $.each($(api.table().footer()).find("select"), function(colIndex) {
    var currData = data.map(function(cols) {
      return cols[colIndex];
    });
    $.each($(this).find("option"), function() {
      if (currData.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1 || $(this).text() == '')
        $(this).attr("disabled", false).show();
      else
        $(this).attr("disabled", true).hide();
    })
  });
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/po70j2gm/)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Doesn't work in IE11 though?

Comment: In IE11 throw a syntax error caused by the arrow function... updated the answer using standard code

Comment: Spoke too soon, the correction stops the dynamic filtering from working. Fiddle works in Chrome, not IE.